# Trying to make a blackjack game kind of

Tags: python, if-statement, blackjack

Summarize the problem

I am trying to make a simple blackjack program that picks two numbers for the dealer 1-11 and two numbers for the player 1-11 also. I want to make a loop that checks if the player is hitting or staying based on what they input, hit or stay. If they hit I want it to add a card to the player deck and give them the option to hit or stay again.

If they stay I want the dealer to check a set of rules and those rules are:

1: does the dealer have less than 17 and does it have less than the player
1a: if it does have less than 17 and less than the player it will draw a new number 1-11 and add it to the dealer hand
1b: it will then run through the loop of checking if it has the following conditions

2: does the dealer have 17-21 and does it have more than the player
2a: if it has any number 17-21 and it has more than the player then it will print a win message

3: does the dealer have over 21
3a: if it has over 21 then it will print a house busted message

4: does the dealer have more than the player
4a: if the dealer has more than the player (but less than 21 because of the previous check) then it will print a house wins message

So that is what I am trying to accomplish with the stay command and so far i haven't found any issues with it.

My hit command however will not register, even if I don't type stay.. I'm trying to debug it by having it print a message and end the loop when i type hit but it still runs through the stay commands regardless, I think it could be an issue with my input converting to a string.

Don't be too harsh on me lol I only taught myself how to code last week and started with python.

Here is my code where I am having issues:

'''

```
                    else:

                        hitstay = True

                        while hitstay:
                            action = str(input("hit or stay? "))
                            dealer = sum(dealer_cards)
                            player = sum(player_cards)
                            if action == 'stay' or 'Stay':
                                if dealer < 17 and dealer < player:
                                    dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
                                    dealer = sum(dealer_cards)
                                    print(f"Dealer pulls {dealer_cards[-1]}\n"
                                          f"Dealer now has {sum(dealer_cards)}")
                                    if 17 <= dealer <= 21 and dealer > player:
                                        print(f"House won! Dealer cards: {dealer_cards}, {sum(dealer_cards)}\n"
                                              f"Player cards: {player_cards}, {sum(player_cards)}")
                                        playing = False
                                        hitstay = False
                                    elif dealer > 21:
                                        print(f'House busted! Dealer cards: {dealer_cards}')
                                        playing = False
                                        hitstay = False
                                    elif dealer > player:
                                        print(f'House wins, Dealer cards {dealer_cards}, {sum(dealer_cards)}\n'
                                              f'Player cards: {player_cards}, {sum(player_cards)}')
                                        playing = False
                                        hitstay = False
                            if action == 'hit' or 'Hit':
                                print('command hit')
                                playing = False
                                hitstay = False
```

'''

Comment: So I also tried putting the if satement to scan for the words hit or Hit before the stay one and i tried making the stay command an if and an elif statement and for some reason no matter what you type it goes through the stay command instead of the hit command. I wonder if it's easier to make the whole thing a function and just call it on a loop but I'm still too new to understand that fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if action == 'stay' or 'Stay':
```

do:

```
if action == 'stay' or action == 'Stay':
```

or:

```
if action in ('stay', 'Stay'):
```

or best of all:

```
if action.lower() == 'stay':
```

---

The first version doesn't work because it's interpreted as:

```
if (action == 'stay') or 'Stay':
```

which is the same as:

```
if (action == 'stay') or True:
```

which is the same as:

```
if True:
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I didn't understand it was seeing the input as a bool.

Comment: Any kind of value can be used in an `if` statement and it will be effectively converted to a bool -- an empty string is "falsey" (i.e. considered as false even though it's not literally `False`), and any other string is "truthy".  The main issue here is the operator precedence, i.e. the fact that `== a or b` is interpreted as `(== a) or (b)` rather than `== (a or b)` -- although if you added the parens around `(a or b)` you wouldn't get the result you want, because `(a or b)` is going to evaluate to one or the other of those values, not a set of both!